# How to download and install LLDB manually for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, lldb

For some reason，I can't access to the Internet on my working computer which has Android Studio 2.1 on it. So I can not install LLDB from buind-in SDK Tools Manager. Is that possible to download an LLDB package individually and install it manually?
Thank you.